use ordinary spotify user account to play music in flutter
I'm currently making an app where, among other things, I want to play music in my Flutter app using Spotify. I've been working on the Spotify API for a while now. So far I've only found the option to play via the Spotify music only w/ the credentials (client ID and serect). But I would like to use the normal user account. that means just email and password.
Is there a way to do this from the API itself, or do I have to control this via a “web browser” within the app?
greets and thanks in advance

Hi @highling have you found any way to do this?
